# How to login in sqlserver when all user disable in sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server-2012

By Mistake i have disable my working user from SQLserver and sa not working
is there is a way to login in sql server ?

Please help me..

Comment: what is the authentication mode, mixed mode or sql server authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Problem statement.

1. All logins that are members of the sysadmin fixed server role have been removed by mistake.
2. All Windows Groups that are members of the sysadmin fixed server role have been removed by mistake.
3. The logins that are members of the sysadmin fixed server role are for individuals who have left the company or who are not available.
4. The sa account is disabled or no one knows the password.

for step by step solution see below link

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx